# Get list item by attribute in Python

Tags: python, list

I need to load a list of database row objects into memory, and then grab one of those rows by its unique ID. Is there a clean, pythonic way of finding an single object from a list by an attribute value? Or do I just loop and compare?

Comment: Is there a reason to not doing this directly with a database query?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you loop and compare:

```
items = [item for item in container if item.attribute == value]
```

And you get back a list which can be tested to see how many you found.

If you will be doing this a lot, consider using a dictionary, where the key is the attribute you're interested in.

Answer (score 21):

If you do this it only gives the very first match, instead of comparing the whole list: [find first sequence item that matches a criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868653/find-first-list-item-that-matches-criteria).

If you do something like this, you don't have to catch the exception but get `None` instead:

```
item = next((i for i in items if i == 'value'), None)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can [filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

```
matches = filter(lambda obj: obj.attribute == "target value", myListOfObjects)
```

Refer to kindall's answer for advice on efficiency. If you're doing this a lot, it's not the right way.

Comment: what would be the right way to do so efficiently? Thanks.