# Find first sequence item that matches a criterion

Tags: python, list

What would be the most elegant and efficient way of finding/returning the first list item that matches a certain criterion?

For example, if I have a list of objects and I would like to get the first object of those with attribute `obj.val==5`. I could of course use list comprehension, but that would incur O(n) and if n is large, it's wasteful. I could also use a loop with `break` once the criterion was met, but I thought there could be a more pythonic/elegant solution.

Comment: what if you want to get the item and the index?

Comment: @CharlieParker, to get both the index and the item, use enumerate() - next((idx, obj) for idx, obj in enumerate(objs) if obj.val==5)

Answer (score 752, accepted):

If you don't have any other indexes or sorted information for your objects, then you will have to iterate until such an object is found:

```
next(obj for obj in objs if obj.val == 5)
```

This is however faster than a complete list comprehension. Compare these two:

```
[i for i in xrange(100000) if i == 1000][0]

next(i for i in xrange(100000) if i == 1000)
```

The first one needs 5.75ms, the second one 58.3µs (100 times faster because the loop 100 times shorter).

Comment: `next` also provides a `default` argument, in the case that no object exists.  E.g. `next((i for i in range(500) if i > 600), 600)` will return 600.

Comment: Python [**`next()`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next)

Comment: Well, this is it, but I just expected the right answer to look cooler. We always advertise python for being so elegant. If you want it to be robust, you should provide `default` (e.g. `None`) - and then you need to not forget that `Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument`... Well, how does this affect readability? E.g. first non-path arugment: `next((arg for arg in sys.argv if not os.path.exists(arg)), None)` - not very friendly.

Comment: True. If it bugs you enough you could always do `def first(items, pred): return next((i for i in items if pred(i)), None)`

Comment: what if you want to find the item and the index too?

Comment: @CharlieParker use `enumerate`: `next((i for i in enumerate(items) if pred(i[1])), None)`.

Comment: Oh, I was soooo hoping this was in the standard library. One more reason to love python!

Comment: an alternate enumerate version: `next(((i, v) for (i, v) in enumerate(items) if pred(v)), None)`  Works exactly the same, but shows the index and value from `enumerate` (yes, we all know how it works, but it doesn't hurt) and lets the predicate work on the value without indexing it.

Comment: @gladed What is `pred` ?I got pred is not defined error

Comment: `pred` is short for predicate, passed into `first()`, and would be a lambda that returns True or False for any i. But I think just using `next()` inline is more pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

This will return the object if found, else it will return `"not found"`

```
a = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]

def search(b):
    try:
        k = a.index(b)
        return a[k] 
    except ValueError:
        return 'not found'

print(search(500))
```

Comment: This is nice, but works only when the criteria is a comparison to list item. I was looking for a more generic solution to handle a wider scope of selection

Comment: but @Jonathan in your question you mentioned **efficient way of finding\returning the first list item** so the above  list a=[100,200,300,400,500]  can contain any type of object not just numbers.

Comment: and I conclude the sentence with "...that matches a certain criteria", which is not the same as to match on equality or identity :)
I did +1 as I think your solution is good for equality\identity private case

Comment: returning a string in case of an error is not a clean solution. for this very case exceptions exist. Also, what if "not found" is actually part of the list?