# Find the first instance of a nonzero number in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
myList = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0]
```

I would like to find the location of the first number in the list that is not equal to zero.

```
myList.index(2.0)
```

It works in this example, but sometimes the first nonzero number will be 1 or 3.

Is there a fast way of doing this?

Comment: just be cautious about comparison with floating point numbers

Comment: I suspect you're getting a lot of down votes because your question does not demonstrate that you've met the ["what have you tried?"](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) requirement. Just a helpful tip for future questions. And also a helpful tip for down-voters, let the user know why you're down voting so that they can make corrections.

Comment: Related: [What is the best way to get the first item from an iterable matching a condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-first-item-from-an-iterable-matching-a-condition), [find first list item that matches criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868653/find-first-list-item-that-matches-criteria)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use `next` with `enumerate`:

```
>>> myList = [0.0 , 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0]
>>> next((i for i, x in enumerate(myList) if x), None) # x!= 0 for strict match
3
```

Comment: What would be the equivalent for numpy arrays ?

Comment: It begs questions about comparison of floating numbers. E.g., what would happen if `42.8/21.4` was used instead of `2.0`? Can you [address](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19502403/edit) comparison of floating numbers in your answer (even if it is somehow automatically handled (rounding, etc.))? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today. And ***without*** reference to this comment.)

Answer (score 21):

Use [filter](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#filter)

Python 2:

```py
myList = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0]
myList2 = [0.0, 0.0]

myList.index(filter(lambda x: x!=0, myList)[0])       # 3
myList2.index(filter(lambda x: x!=0, myList2)[0])     # IndexError
```

Python 3: (Thanks for Matthias's comment):

```py
myList.index(next(filter(lambda x: x!=0, myList)))    # 3
myList2.index(next(filter(lambda x: x!=0, myList2)))  # StopIteration
```

```
# from Ashwini Chaudhary's answer
next((i for i, x in enumerate(myList) if x), None)    # 3
next((i for i, x in enumerate(myList2) if x), None)   # None
```

You have to handle special case.

Comment: Great alternative too, main difference from `next` is that `next` provides a default value whereas this would raise an exception.

Comment: for python 3 you can use `myList.index(next(filter(lambda x: x!=0, myList)))`

Comment: I like this answer best, but with the Matthias mod to use "next".  
Note that in either case, depending on the situation you should consider a test of any(myList) first, to make sure there is at least one nonzero value.  It may help with program flow and avoiding exceptions.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [numpy.nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html):

```
myList = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0]
I = np.nonzero(myList)
# The first index is necessary because the vector is within a tuple
first_non_zero_index = I[0][0]
# 3
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a one liner to do it:

```
val = next((index for index,value in enumerate(myList) if value != 0), None)
```

Basically, it uses [next()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) to find the first value, or return `None` if there isn't one. [enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is used to make an iterator that iterates over index,value tuples so that we know the index that we're at.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
[i for i, x in enumerate(myList) if x][0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `next` with `enumerate` is excellent when the array is large. For smaller arrays, I would use `argmax` from NumPy so that you won't need a loop:

```py
import numpy as np

myList = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0]
myArray = np.array(myList)
np.argmax(myArray > 0)
3
```

Comment: This will not find the first nonzero element, e.g. for `[0, 0, 1, 2]`.

Comment: Yes it will, but it's not very intuitive.  All elements in `myArray > 0` are either `False` or `True`, so the maximum of that array is `True`.  According to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) for numpy.argmax, "In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices corresponding to the first occurrence are returned."  So with your example, if `myArray` is `[0, 0, 1, 2]`, then `myArray > 0` is `[False, False, True, True]` and the `argmax` of that is 2.

Answer (score 1):

What about using enumerate? Check the [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) documentation.

```
def first_non_zero(mylist):
  for index, number in enumerate(mylist):
    if number != 0: # or 'if number:'
      return index
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
print (np.nonzero(np.array(myList))[0][0])
```

This is more convenient, because along with finding nonzero values, this can also help to apply logic function directly. For example:

```
print (np.nonzero(np.array(myList)>1))
```

Comment: Perhaps elaborate a little bit in your answer how floating point comparisons are handled? Presumably it is not *exact* comparison. (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a list comprehension:

```
myDict = {x: index for index, x in enumerate(myList) if x}
```

The indices of the nonzero elements are `myDict[element]`.

Comment: This doesn't give the index, it just filters out the non-zero elements from the list.