# Delete rows in subsequences that contain leading zeros in a dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in following format with a time series

```
A  B  C  201401 201402 201403

a1 b1 c1  100    200    300
a2 b2 c2  0      250     0
```

I have used [Pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) to flatten this data and have got following format.

```
A  B  C  YYYYMM Value
a1 b1 c1 201401 100
a1 b1 c1 201402 200
a1 b1 c1 201403 300
a2 b2 c2 201401 0
a2 b2 c2 201402 250
a2 b2 c2 201403 0
```

Now for a particular combination of [A B C] I only want the time series **starting from** non zero values.so my output should be like this.

```
A  B  C  YYYYMM Value
a1 b1 c1 201401 100
a1 b1 c1 201402 200
a1 b1 c1 201403 300
a2 b2 c2 201402 250
a2 b2 c2 201403 0
```

I tried,

```
df.groupby(['A','B','C']).apply(lambda x: x['Value'][np.where(x['Value']>0)[0][0]:]
```

This just gives me time series and doesn't imply inplace changes.
What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: why don't you just filter the dataframe `df = df[df['Value'] > 0]`?

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars=['A', 'B', 'C']).query('value > 0')`?

Comment: Hi This will eliminate all the zero values in time series.
I just want to eliminate leading zeroes. I have changed the example for reference.

Comment: I see no leading zeros in your examples, a leading zero in a number should be like this 0100

Comment: if you see A,B,C as a group and having a time series with values 0,250,0 according to me 250 , 0 are leading zero eliminated time series.

Answer (score 0):

I continued with your idea of grouping and then filtering. The basic idea was to take each group and find the first non-zero Value's index assuming they are already sorted by date. And then just ungroup and clean up.

```
def applyFunc(row):
    row_values = np.array(row.Value)
    first_non_zero_index = next((i for i, x in enumerate(row_values) if x), None)
    return row.iloc[first_non_zero_index:]

df.groupby(['A','B','C']).apply(applyFunc).drop(["A","B","C"],axis=1).reset_index().drop("level_3",axis=1)
```

Uses a snippet from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19502403/2750819