# Find element in list of objects with explicit key value

Tags: python, python-2.7, types

I have a list of objects in python:

```
accounts = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': 'Example Account 1'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': 'Gow to get this one?'
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'title': 'Example Account 3'
    },
]
```

I need to get object with id=2.

How can I select a proper object from this list, when I know only the value of the object attributes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find object in list that has attribute equal to some value (that meets any condition)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125467/find-object-in-list-that-has-attribute-equal-to-some-value-that-meets-any-condi)

Answer (score 34):

Given your data structure:

```
>>> [item for item in accounts if item.get('id')==2]
[{'title': 'Gow to get this one?', 'id': 2}]
```

If item does not exist:

```
>>> [item for item in accounts if item.get('id')==10]
[]
```

---

That being said, if you have opportunity to do so, you might rethink your datastucture:

```
accounts = {
    1: {
        'title': 'Example Account 1'
    },
    2: {
        'title': 'Gow to get this one?'
    },
    3: {
        'title': 'Example Account 3'
    }
}
```

You might then be able to access you data directly by indexing their `id` or using [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) depending how you want to deal with non-existent keys.

```
>>> accounts[2]
{'title': 'Gow to get this one?'}

>>> accounts[10]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 10

>>> accounts.get(2)
{'title': 'Gow to get this one?'}
>>> accounts.get(10)
# None
```

Comment: might be better to use `if item.get('id') == 2` in case some dict does not contain the key

Comment: as for why the data structure, I can say that I've simply been HANDED such a structure that needs ETL work... wasn't really optional that it was a [{...},{...}] format... just had to find if a key was present in any of said objects to solve a particular need.

Answer (score 9):

The other answers are very old. The best way is with `next()`.

```
next(account for account in accounts if account['id'] == 2)
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9868665/1812732

Comment: Agree. *Note:* One will have to either handle a `StopIteration` or pass a default value to `next(iterator, default)`

Answer (score 1):

This will return any element from the list that has an id == 2

```
limited_list = [element for element in accounts if element['id'] == 2]
>>> limited_list
[{'id': 2, 'title': 'Gow to get this one?'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a weird data structure, but it can be done:

```
acc = [account for account in accounts if account['id'] == 2][0]
```

Maybe a dictionary with the id-number as key is more appropriate, as this makes the accessing easier:

```
account_dict = {account['id']: account for account in accounts}
```