# Finding last item that matches criteria in Python

Tags: python

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9868665/433570 finds the first item.

I can think of doing `reverse` first before applying the solution above. 
But then I would end up with two `reverse` which might be avoided.

Is there a better solution than using two `reverse` and `next` ?

Comment: If you are willing to use numpy: `np.where(np.array(my_list) == criteria_value)[0][-1]`

Answer (score 12):

Instead of reversing the list, which may be a lengthy operation (`l.reverse()`) because it **reverses the whole list**, I'd simply use a **reversed iterator** `reversed(l)` with whatever matching method you want, since you can stop early at the first match, it may save you time vs reversing the whole list.

Of course there's best case and worst cases for both methods, below may give you an idea, based on where the match is in the list (e.g. towards the end, the beginning, or the middle)

```
In [1]: l = range(0, 100000)

In [2]: %timeit next((i for i in reversed(l) if i == 1), None)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.94 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit next((i for i in reversed(l) if i == 50000), None)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.39 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit next((i for i in reversed(l) if i == 99000), None)
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.4 µs per loop
```

Below is an idea of how long it takes to reverse the same list:

```
In [5]: %timeit l.reverse()
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.5 µs per loop
```

<sub>**Note:** I ran above on Python 2, so `range()` is a list not an iterator, so no need to `list(range())` it to make the comparison worthwhile.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer in related questions suggested to use an iterator on the list to build a generator containing only matching elements and take first element from that generator:

```
next(obj for obj in objs if condition)
```

You can do the same using range in opposite order:

```
next(objs[i] for i in range(len(objs) -1, -1, -1))
```

(use `xrange` in Python2)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = range(11)
y = next((i for i in reversed(x) if i % 2 == 1), None)
```

Comment: i.e. find the last odd number in the list.

Comment: I'd suggest explaining what you're doing and why, since you've offered a new approach to the OP