# itertools 'previous' (opposite of next) python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I'm currently using something like

```
>> import itertools
>> ABC = [a, b, c]
>> abc = itertools.cycle( ABC )
>> next( abc )
a
>> next( abc )
b    
>> next( abc )
c
```

I want my next call to be

```
>> previous( abc )
b
```

Is there a method in itertools that can accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a python iterator go backwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777188/making-a-python-iterator-go-backwards)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Because of the way Python's iteration protocol works, it would be impossible to implement `previous` without keeping the entire history of the generated values. Python doesn't do this, and given the memory requirements you probably wouldn't want it to.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that's why I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `deque` from `collections` module and `rotate` method,
for example:

```
from collections import deque

alist=['a','b','c']
d=deque(alist)

current = d[0] 
print(current) # 'a'

d.rotate(1) # rotate one step to the right
current = d[0] 
print(current) # 'c'

d.rotate(-1) # rotate one step to the left
current = d[0] 
print(current) # 'a' again
```

Answer (score 5):

You can write your own class to emulate an `iterable` object with next and previous. This is the simplest implementation:

```
class cycle:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self._c = c
        self._index = -1

    def __next__(self):
        self._index += 1
        if self._index>=len(self._c):
            self._index = 0
        return self._c[self._index]

    def previous(self):
        self._index -= 1
        if self._index < 0:
            self._index = len(self._c)-1
        return self._c[self._index]

ABC = ['a', 'b', 'c']
abc = cycle(ABC)
print(next(abc))
print(next(abc))
print(next(abc))
print(abc.previous())
```

Comment: That doesn't work on arbitrary iterable objects (such as a range or any of the iterables produced by itertools). It only works on indexable objects.

Comment: Of course it doesn't! But the example was indexable, so this code works on it.

Answer (score 3):

Although `deque` is the way to go, here's another example:

**Code**

```
import itertools as it


class Cycle:
    """Wrap cycle."""
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self._container = it.cycle(seq)
        self._here = None
        self.prev = None

    def __iter__(self):
        return self._container

    def __next__(self):
        self.prev = self._here
        self._here = next(self._container)
        return self._here
```

**Demo**

```
c = Cycle("abc")
next(c)
# 'a'
next(c)
# 'b'
c.prev
# 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same when I came across your question.
Though there's no **previous** but you can use next with **reversed** for similar effect.

```py
next((item for item in reversed(_list) if condition), None)
```

[Taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37967152/1635133)