# How to go through next and previous list items with buttons?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a list:

```
files = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png", "image5.png", "image6.png"]
```

And PyQt5 buttons and a label:

[image]

How can I have the first item of the list **on the label** and go through the list one by one with the:

**Next button** (*click*, image2.png, *click*, image3.png, *click*, image4.png...)

**Previous button** (*click*, image3.png, *click*, image2.png, *click*, image1.png...)

And the label should update accordingly.

I've tried all day and searched for answers but couldn't get it to work. [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611890/itertools-previous-opposite-of-next-python) could help maybe, my skills weren't enough to utilize the advice, though.

All the code to create the above window with buttons:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._files = deque()
        self._filesCount = len(self._files)
        self._setupUI()
        self._connectSignalsSlots()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 button - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        button = QPushButton('Print Files List', self)
        button.move(100,70)
        button.clicked.connect(self.loadFiles)

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        button = QPushButton('Print Next Filename', self)
        button.move(160,110)
        button.clicked.connect(self.nextFilename)
        label = QLabel('image1.png (should be first of the list, \n and update with button presses)', self)
        label.move(35,140)

        button = QPushButton('Print Previous Filename', self)
        button.move(10,110)
        button.clicked.connect(self.previousFilename)

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def loadFiles(self):
        files = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png", "image5.png", "image6.png"]
        if len(files) > 0:
            for file in files:
                print(file)

    def nextFilename(self):
        print('nextFilenameButton click')

    def previousFilename(self):
        print('previousFilenameButton click')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to handle an index (or cursor) that serves to obtain the filename. And that index must be modified through the buttons

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel, QPushButton, QWidget


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._current_index = 0
        self._filenames = []

        self.previous_button = QPushButton("Previous")
        self.next_button = QPushButton("Next")
        self.print_button = QPushButton("Print")
        self.label = QLabel()

        lay = QGridLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.previous_button, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.next_button, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.print_button, 0, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 3)

        self.previous_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_previous)
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_next)
        self.print_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_print)

        self._update_button_status(False, True)

        self.load_files()

    def load_files(self):
        self._filenames = [
            "image1.png",
            "image2.png",
            "image3.png",
            "image4.png",
            "image5.png",
            "image6.png",
        ]
        self.current_index = 0

    def handle_next(self):
        self.current_index += 1

    def handle_previous(self):
        self.current_index -= 1

    def handle_print(self):
        for filename in self._filenames:
            print(filename)

    @property
    def current_index(self):
        return self._current_index

    @current_index.setter
    def current_index(self, index):
        if index <= 0:
            self._update_button_status(False, True)
        elif index >= (len(self._filenames) - 1):
            self._update_button_status(True, False)
        else:
            self._update_button_status(True, True)

        if 0 <= index < len(self._filenames):
            self._current_index = index
            filename = self._filenames[self._current_index]
            pixmap = QPixmap(filename)
            self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def _update_button_status(self, previous_enable, next_enable):
        self.previous_button.setEnabled(previous_enable)
        self.next_button.setEnabled(next_enable)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note: Having 2 methods with the same name is useless since in python only the last implementation will be used.

Comment: Whoops, the same name thing slipped in when I was condensing the code. But thank you so much! This is better than I could've wished for! :) However, what do I need to type to get the current filename for a label text?

Comment: Ah, managed to realize it! 
Make a new label and add `self.label2.setText(filename)` below the `self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)` line :)

Comment: @ManuJärvinen My example is trivial and I don't intend to implement a lot of functionality. Please avoid adding comments that do not argue about my answer.

Comment: Sorry :( Was just thinking of people who want to go the next step with this. Thank you for the answer. (Okay, no more comments)

Comment: @ManuJärvinen Here we do not help to implement projects (since it seems that your comments are going to do it) but to solve a specific problem, we do not intend to cover much but the minimum and necessary because that way we can have a quality Q&A collection. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]