# Returning the last element in a list larger than some threshold

Tags: python, list, loops, element, threshold

Say we have the following list in Python:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,4,6,3,1,9,4,3,8,4,2,3,4,4,1,8]
```

How can we return the last element which is considered `>=4`?

I tried doing a for-loop and looking for the index, but felt that I went through some mess, apart from getting the unexpected result, and thought there might be an easier way to go about it.

Thanks.

Comment: `[x for x in lst if x >= 4][-1]`

Comment: So what is your expected outcome for this list? 8? As it is the last value that is greater than or equal to 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding last item that matches criteria in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966943/finding-last-item-that-matches-criteria-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse `lst` with `reversed`, and call `next`.

```
next(i for i in reversed(lst) if i >= 4)
8
```

This is efficient because it only iterates the minimum amount that it needs to, to return a result. This is equivalent to:

```
for i in reversed(lst):
    if i >= 4:
        break

print(i)
8
```

It so often happens that no element exists that meets your condition, and so `next` has nothing to return at all. In this case, `next` returns a `StopIteration` you can avoid by using calling the function with a default argument -

```
next((i for i in reversed(lst) if i >= 4), None)
```

Which returns `None` if no element meets the condition `i >= 4`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,4,6,3,1,9,4,3,8,4,2,3,4,4,1,8]
>>> x1 = []
>>> num = 4
>>> for i in x:
...     if i >= num:
...             x1.append(i)
...
>>> print(x1)
[4, 5, 4, 6, 9, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8]
>>> max(x1)
9
```